# How to create the ListNavigation using user's value

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

the ListNavigation in ActionBarSherlock takes in values from array.xml in res.

```
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Is it possible to use user's values to be the texts in the navigator list? i.e. programmatically pass in the String values to the ArrayAdapter instead of createFromResource.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add in your own ArrayList of strings and then add to the arraylist or the array adapter and it should work fine

```
ArrayList<String> mItems = new ArrayList<Strings>();
```

.
.
.

```
Context C = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(); 
ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, mItems);
list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Then you can add/delete/update items in your string array list

```
mItems.add("Some Item") or list.add("Other item");
```

That should do it